# Understanding "like" vs equal in T-SQL to rewrite where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My original statement is

```
where charindex(';' + tableA.Col1 + ';' , ';' + Table.col2 + ';') > 0
```

I want to rewrite this. First I use in a join condition

```
on (';' + Table.col2 + ';') like  ('%;' + tableA.Col1 + ';%')
```

This gives the same result. But then I think why concatenate the semicolons

```
on Table.col2 like  ('%' + tableA.Col1 + '%')
```

Which also gives the same result. But since I concatenate `;` on both sides I thought maybe they were after equal on both sides:

```
on Table.col2 = tableA.Col1
```

But this does not give the same result. Is there a way to use the equality sign instead of `like`? It does not make sense can anyone explain? Why has the first statement concatenation of `;` of both sides?

Comment: It's the `%` which is important. The other 2 are checking if the value inside `col1` appears in `col2`. Though I smell a column storing delimited data (using `;`), which is the *real* problem. The `;` were there, as then a value like `'end'` wouldn't match the value `'ending'`. `'%end%'` *is* `LIKE` the value `'ending;start;middle'` however, `'%;end;%` is *not* `LIKE` `';ending;start;middle;'`

Comment: @Larnu thanks! It makes sense with delimited data, you are right I have seen examples of in the data... Is it possible to use `=` with some trick? It will make the query alot faster :-)

Comment: @David: the "trick" would be to fix your design, so you are storing each value of the delimited list in a separate row. *Then* you can use `=`.

Comment: @GMB it is not my desing I just started a new job :-). I am just trying to make a query run faster...

Comment: @Larnu But `;end;` = `;end;` so why does equality not work?  Which senario does equality not catch? It seems to me that with a semicolon we exclude your example but why not use equality then?

Comment: @Larnu I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @GMB, well how do I change the design with SQL code?

Comment: *"But `;end; = ;end;`"* *but* `';end;'` does *not* equal `';end;start;'` @David . This is why fixing your design is the *real* solution here.

Comment: @David, Why the desire to change the syntax or the way the predicate is written? The logical basis of the predicate is, by it's very nature, nonSARGable. This cannot be rewritten such that you will go from a scan to a seek.